# Spring, Neo4j, Java - scala-maven-plugin:3.1.0 error

Tags: java, scala, maven, neo4j

When I try import neo4j maven project for example (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.0.1/community/cypher/cypher-docs), I get this error (https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7f89xzbzz4qm43/scala.png). Is any chance how to fix? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `m2e-scala`. M2E is what is giving this error, and there is a special eclipse plugin for scala using m2e.

Use this [update site](http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site) to install it as an eclipse plugin.

Comment: Thx, but still the same problem. Downloaded from github. Imported to Eclipse, m2eclipse-scala in Project Explorer Run As Maven Install.

Comment: It's an eclipse plugin. Don't download from the git, use the update site.